# What would be the best way to synchronize my application's time with outside server's time?

Tags: c#, synchronization, clock

I was thinking of changing system's local time to server's time and then use it but I bet there are other ways to do this. I've been trying to find something like a clock in c#, but couldnt find anything. I'm receiving server's time in a DateTime format.

edit:
I need my application to use while working same time server does. I just want to get server's time once and after that, make my application work in a while loop using the time I've obtained from the server. There might be a difference between my system's time and server's time (even 5 seconds) and that's why I want to do this.

Comment: Are you actually talking about clock synchronization or time zones? It would help if you could give more detail.

Comment: edited :P, sorry for unclear question

Comment: Note that changing local system time not only unfriendly operation, it also requires admin privilegies on most version of Windows.

Comment: I've added a code for you to change the local time. you can either save the timezone id in config at the client, or send it from server to the client

Comment: @Patryk: Your question is *still* not clear. Are you concerned that the server and the local application are in different time zones? If so, use UTC in both places. Or are you concerned that the local system clock will show something different to the server clock for other reasons (e.g. being 5 minutes slow)?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question like few mins ago and added in there '(even 5 seconds)'.

Comment: Can you provide a scenario in which you explain why the time in your application needs to be 'exactly' the same as on your server? What problem will occur when there is a slight difference?

Comment: Example: I can send a request to a server once a 5 minutes. There is many people trying to send request at specified time (let's say 12:30:00). Only 1 request closest to that time will be accepted by a the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer @JonSkeet's provided to synch the times looks good, I just wanted to point out some things.

As @Alexei already said, users require admin privileges to be able to change their local time (in Windows as least), but there may also be other issues that can cause the time to be out of synch (bad internet connection, hacks etc.). This means there is no guarantee that the client time is indeed the same as the server time, so you will at least need to check the time the request was received serverside anyway. Plus there might also be a usability issue at hand here, would I want an application to be able change the time of my own local machine? Hell no.

To sum things up:

- Check the time of the request serverside at least
- Don't change the time of the client machine but show some kind of indicator in your application

How to handle the indicator in your application can be done in various ways.

- Show a clock in your application (your initial idea) that is periodically synched with the server
- Show some kind of countdown (*"you can submit after x seconds.."*), push a resetCountdown request to the clients when a request is received.
- Enable a 'send button' or what ever you have, this would work kind of similar to the countdown.

Just remember, it's nearly impossible validate a request such as this clientside. So you have to build in some checks serverside!

I actually wanted to write a comment but it got kind of long.. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not entirely clear what you mean, but you could certainly create your own `IClock` interface which you'd use everywhere in code, and then write an implementation of that which is regularly synchronized with your server (or with NTP).

My [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project already uses the idea of an injectable clock - not for synchronization purposes, but for testability. (A time service is basically a dependency.) Basically the idea is workable :) You may well not find anything which already does this, but it shouldn't be too hard to write. You'll want to think about how to adjust time though - for example, if the server time gets ahead of your "last server time + local time measurements" you may want to slew it gradually rather than having a discrete jump.

This is always assuming you *do* want it to be local to your application, of course. Another alternative (which may well not be appropriate, depending on your context) is to require that the host runs a time synchronization client (I *believe* Windows does by default these days) and simply start failing if the difference between your server and the client gets too large. (It's never going to be *exactly* in sync anyway, or at least not for long - you'll need to allow for *some* leeway.)

Comment: @jonskeet , I've looked at the Noda Time project, and if I may humbally recommend an extension: I've done something similar in Java (though much less impressive) and it helped us to also use injected timers and executors that worked on the injected time. so in real time we used real timers and executors, but for testing purposes we were able to run all timers and executors on a single thread while controlling their advencment.

Comment: @omerschleifer: I'm afraid that isn't really enough description to understand what you mean. We do provide a FakeClock implementation - but Noda Time isn't meant to be a threading library. It would make a reasonable *side-project* to have a threading library which worked well with Noda Time, but I don't think it ought to be part of Noda Time itself.

Answer (score 1):

Okay a bit of necromancy as this is 6 years old, but had to deal with a similar problem for a network game.

Employed a technique I referred to as "marco-polo" for reasons that will be obvious soon. It requires the two clocks to be able to exchange messages, and its accuracy is dependent on how fast they can do that.

Disclaimer: I am fairly certain I am not the first to do this, and that this is the most rudimentary way to synchronize two clocks. Still I didn't find a documented way of doing so.

At Clock B (The clock we're trying to synchronize) we do the following ::

```
// Log the timestamp
localTime_Marco_Send = DateTime.UtcNow;

// Send that to clock A
SendSyncRequest();

// Wait for an answer
Sleep(..);
```

At Clock A (the reference clock) we have the following handler ::

```
// This is triggered by SendSyncRequest
OnReceiveSyncRequest()
{
    // We received "Marco" - Send "Polo"
    SendSyncReply(DateTime.UtcNow);
}
```

And back at Clock B ::

```
// This is triggered by SendSyncReply
OnReceiveSyncReply(DateTime remoteHalfTime)
{
    // Log the time we received it
    DateTime localTime_Polo_Receive = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // The remote time is somewhere between the two local times
    // On average, it will be in the middle of the two
    DateTime localHalfTime = localTime_Marco_Send  + 
         (localTime_Polo_Receive - localTime_Marco_Send) / 2;

    // As a result, the estimated dT from A to B is
    TimeSpan estimatedDT_A_B = localHalfTime - remoteHalfTime;
}
```

As a result we now have access to a nifty TimeSpan we can subtract from our current local time to estimate the remote time

```
DateTime estimatedRemoteTime = DateTime.UtcNow - estimatedDT_A_B;
```

The accuracy of this estimate is subject to the Round Trip Time of send-receive-send-receive, and you should also account for Clock drift (you should be doing this more than once):

1. Round-trip-time. If it were instant, you'd have the exact dT. If it takes 1 second to come and return, you don't know if the delay was on the sending or the receiving. As a result, your error is 0 < e < RTT, and on average will be RTT/2. If you know send (or receive) takes more than the other, use that to your advantage - the time you received is not the half-time, but is shifted relatively to how long each leg takes
2. Clock drift. CPU clocks drift, maybe 1s per day. So poll again once potential drift may play an important role.

Answer (score 0):

Your server should always save the time in UTC mode.
You save time in UTC like this in the server:

```
  DateTime utcTime = new DateTime(0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

or:

```
    DateTime utcTimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

In the client, when you get the time which is stored in utc you can sonvert it to local time like this:

```
    public DateTime ToLocalTime(DateTime utcTime)
    {
        //Assumes that even if utcTime kind is no properly deifned it is indeed UTC time
        DateTime serverTime= new DateTime(utcTime.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(serverTime, m_localTimeZone);            
    }
```

If You want to change your local time zone , here is a code example on how to read time zone to use from config:

```
string localTimeZoneId = sysParamsHelper.ReadString(LOCAL_TIME_ZONE_ID_KEY, LOCAL_TIME_ZONE_DEFAULT_ID);
    ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

    foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo in timeZones)
    {                
       if(timeZoneInfo.Id.Equals(localTimeZoneId))
       {
           m_localTimeZone = timeZoneInfo;
           break;
       }
    }

    if (m_localTimeZone == null)
    {
        m_logger.Error(LogTopicEnum.AMR, "Could not find time zone with id: " + localTimeZoneId + " . will use default time zone (UTC).");
        m_localTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
    }
```

Comment: I don't *think* the OP is really talking about time zones, but I've asked for clarification...

Comment: OK , if I understand now, what he wants is code to change local time zone? I've added a code sample to my answer.

Comment: Even difference of 5 seconds is something, that I would like to avoid. I'm not sure how else my question could be clarified