# Keeping my submitted client side datetime in sync with my timer job

Tags: c#, datetime

I submit a datetime from my client side to my server.  Lets say its 1:00pm California time.  Upon the submission of this data, I parse the time and convert it UTC like so:

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.ParseExact(model.SessionStart, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime(), DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

I have a timerjob running on the same server that checks for these dates that are less than the current time so my code runs when the session start time is at the right time.

How can I keep all these times in sync with my server so that if someone submits from california, or new york everything is converted properly and my timerjob will run correctly.

Comment: Sounds like a horrible idea what you're doing. I'm finding it difficult to think of a case that would justify synchronizing server timer with client time data. Use just server times, store them in your session or whatever equivalent you have, and even then I smell something wrong with the design itself; if you care to share details  on how you use these timers probably someone here will give you a better design

Comment: for instance, if I had an auction, that I let the user set the start and end time.. wouldn't that be a case for this?  When I get the user submitted datetime i would just need to find a way so if my server is california time and they submit from newyork it knows to run the timer job at the right time

Comment: what I'm finding suspicious is the "timer" on the server. I hope you're not trying to use actual Timer class or something of the kind. For the submitted date to be correct make sure you're submitting it in UTC format, not just DateTime.Now.ToString()

Comment: @StenPetrov, what is smelly about the server using a timer to periodiclly check if the auction is starting/ending? as long as the actual check is in utc and the server clock is in sync?

Comment: @omerschleifer timers are inherently unreliable, locking up in a timer tick event can prevent further events or queue up many events to fire up in rapid succession, and that's without even considering resource locking across threads or race conditions. On top of that bugs caused in/by timer events are very difficult to troubleshoot.  An auction site could very well record post data and bid data and then determine bid winner only upon bidding or requesting results. Requesting the results can happen via JS timer on the client page, sparing the server resources that need not be occupied.

Comment: @StenPetrov I have thought about that solution, but what if no one hits the auctions or bids.. how would i send an email out when the auction is over if no one is hitting it right at the end of the auction.  I know timer jobs are unreliable, but determining a result at a specific time is necessary for me because I have to send out emails upon the auction end time,I can't simply wait for someone to bid or request the results on the client end

Comment: @anthonypliu you can write a separate windows service that runs an endless loop where it checks if any new auctions have finished and if so - send the email then sleeps for 5 seconds (no timers, sleeps). If written well your service can run on a separate server, it will not crash if your main server crashes or the other way around; it will not interfere with appdomain recycling in IIS and will not cause locks or downgrade your page performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach for the auction will be to let the client send the server start time and end time in UTC, and let the server timers compare Utc time now to the auction start/end time. there is no need to use the local time of the server here at all.

The only local time to use, is in the client dispaly.
any dealing with the server and within the server should be always in UTC only.

And as for time synchronization, you can use something like NODA time as suggested here by John Skeet:
[What would be the best way to synchronize my application's time with outside server's time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130459/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-synchronize-my-applications-time-with-outside-ser)